# Prevent special characters longer than container to cause word break

Tags: javascript, html, css

If a user enters a URL, or a long word that contains a question mark or a hyphen, the word will break(longer than its container with `overflow: auto`). I can use the Unicode non-breaking hyphen to fix the hyphen issue but there is nothing similar for question mark.

Also having `{}[]` or `[][]` or `[]{}` also causes a word break

Here is an example of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/f53watec/37/

I'm trying to have the div element look exactly like the section element without the string breaking from any special characters

Comment: Hi! *"Here is an example of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/f53watec/37/"* The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code/markup/examples) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that ? is treated as whitespace. So if you add:

```
white-space: pre;
```

It should work. If you want other lines to break you would need to put a e.g a span around the word and put the rule only on this span.

You can also use the `<nobr>` tag around the URL.

I think it is not possible to treat special characters not as whitespace using css only. (If I am wrong please correct me anyone!)

Comment: That prevents the special characters from breaking the word, but not to the extent I want. The only way to do a new line would be by pressing enter and I only want very long words to be part of the overflow